# Weird NetworkOnMainThread exception

Tags: android

I'm new to android, please halp.

This is a really simple scenario, there's an actionbar, and when a tab is selected, I need to send an http request to get an article list, when the response arrives, update a listview and here's where I got this exception.

I'm aware that I should isolate network operations from UI thread, so I implement the network functions in an AsyncTask class.

The most weird part is, before I try to get the article list, I have actually called a network function once to log in, and that just works fine, no exceptions! And guess what, if I replace the get article list call with log in call, it works fine, too. All the code are just the same, except the arguments differ.

Here's how I do it, since too many modules will use the network module, I use a static wrapper:

UI -> Static Factory -> New AsyncTask -> Response arrives -> Call Static callback function in Static Factory -> Call callback function in UI

AsyncTask doInBackground

```
@Override
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String uri = params[0];
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
    try {
        return _client.execute(get);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }   
}
```

AsyncTask post execute

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse result) {
        //Do something with result
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = FormJsonFromResponse();
                Command.OnTaskComplete(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

static wrapper code:

```
@Override
    public static void OnTaskComplete(JSONObject json) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(_callback != null) {
            _callback.OnCommandComplete(json);
        }
    }
```

Here's how I call asynctask in static wrapper:

```
public static void LogIn(String user, String pass) {
    new NetworkTask().execute(_uriPrefix + login, _user, _pass);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, don't have that at hand, will post it later. I am now avoiding this by resetting the strict mode which I think is not recommended. so try to find a decent way to get over it.

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThread` exception because of your are using internet function in main thread, instead of you have to put your networking related code in the `AsyncTask --> doInBackground()`.

Comment: @AbdulRahman If you would take the time to read the post, you would see he's done that already.

Comment: I'd like to see your `FormJsonFromResponse()` body. My guess is that because the data response you receive is much larger than a login response, that you're actually receiving bytes on the open socket in `FormJsonFromResponse()`, which you ARE running on the UI thread.

Comment: @323go oh, sounds quite possible! the article list is actually long. FormJsonFromResponse() is just as simple as: new JSONObject(new String(EntityUtil.toByteArray(response.getEntity()))).  So how should I avoid this too many bytes scenario? thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revise your AsyncTask following this pattern:

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String uri = params[0];
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = _client.execute(get);
        return FormJsonFromResponse();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }   
}
```

AsyncTask post execute

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    //Do something with result
    if (result != null) {
        try {
            Command.OnTaskComplete( result );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: great! will try this out and post the result later!